# Can I run Webpack in a Python app on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webpack, google-cloud-platform

The tutorial for running [Webpack](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/resources/tools/webpack) on the Google Cloud Platform assumes a nodejs runtime. Is there a way to run it on an existing app that's running Python? I'd like to start sprinkling the app with some Webpack+ React love.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAE allows your app to have multiple modules, and there is at least some support for having different modules use different languages, but I haven't tried it myself.

One important question is whether you are using the "Standard Environment" or the "Flexible Environment" for your app.  Node.js is only supported on the Flexible Environment.  See [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs).

So if you are able to use the Flexible Environment, it may be possible to have a single app with both Python and Node.js.  I say "may" because GAE doesn't always support all combinations with its various features.